# Can a method within a class inherit a subroutine that executes at the start and end of the method?

Tags: c#, logging, c#-4.0

I have a logger that I am adding to my project. Right now for every method I'm going to have to write Logger.DebugLog("Starting Method") at the start of each method and Logger.DebugLog("Completed Method")

this logger - when Debug enabled - allows me to track exactly what methods were called on this run so that if there is an issue I can see how far it got before breaking making it easy to debug. Assume that the method name and line are being captured - **my goal here is I do not want to add those two lines on every one of the +100 public or private methods**

```
namespace myProject
{
   public class myClass
   {
     public bool MyPublicMethod(string Message = "someRandomMessage")
     {
        try
        {
            myPrivateMethod(1);
            writeToLog(Message);
            return true;
        }
        catch(){
           return false; 
        }
     }

     private bool myPrivateMethod(int passedNumber)
     {
        try
        {
            writeToLog(passedNumber);
            return true;
        }
        catch(){
           return false;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

my log file should look like this:

```
04:00:00 - Starting Method:MyPublicMethod
04:00:00 - Starting Method:myPrivateMethod
04:00:01 - 1
04:00:01 - Completed Method:myPrivateMethod
04:00:02 - someRandomMessage
04:00:02 - Completed Method:MyPublicMethod
```

What I am forced to do now which looks cluttered is:

```
namespace myProject
{
   public class myClass
   {
     public bool MyPublicMethod(string Message = "someRandomMessage")
     {
        try
        {
            writeToLog("Starting Method");
            myPrivateMethod(1);
            writeToLog(Message);

            writeToLog("Completed Method");
            return true;
        }
        catch(){
           return false; 
        }
     }

     private bool myPrivateMethod(int passedNumber)
     {
        try
        {
            writeToLog("Starting Method");
            writeToLog(passedNumber);

            writeToLog("Completed Method");
            return true;
        }
        catch(){
           return false;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

is this even possible in .NET or do I have to explicitly list that logging method if I want to use it?

---

**4/6/18 Edit:** It is possible - see AOP. Heres a pretty decent article on it http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1305/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-csharp-using-solid
Here is a good summary of exactly what I was looking for:

> Consider the following code:

```
public class DocumentSource : IDocumentSource
{
    //..     
    public Document[] GetDocuments(string format)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = CreateEFContext())
            {
                var documents =
                    context
                        .Documents
                        .Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith("." + format))
                        .ToArray();

                logger.LogSuccess(
                    "Obtained " + documents.Length + " documents of type " + format +
                    Environment.NewLine +
                    "Connection String: " + connectionString);

                 return documents;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           logger.LogError(
               "Error obtaining documents of type " + format +
               Environment.NewLine +
               "Connection String: " + connectionString, ex);

            throw;
        }
    }     
    //..
}
```

> Here is how the method would look like without logging:

```
public Document[] GetDocuments(string format)
{
    using (var context = CreateEFContext())
    {
        return
            context
                .Documents
                .Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith("." + format))
                .ToArray();
    }
}
```

> Clearly, the logging code has made the original method less readable. It has tangled the real method code with logging code.
>   This is also a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.
>   Also, we expect to find the same logging pattern in many methods all over the code base. Basically, we expect to find the following pattern:

```
try
{
    //Do something here

    logger.LogSuccess(…                
    //..
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(…
    throw;
}
```

Comment: You can look at Aspect-Oriented programming - this is a compilation step that will automatically inject code into your methods, and logging the start and end of a method is a common example. There are various AOP tools out there.

Comment: You *do* know you have stack trace information that already provides the info you are logging, right?

Comment: @InBetween Only if he has thrown an exception, or generated a stack trace manually...for general logging of the start and end of methods, I don't think your comment applies?

Comment: @RB. well I was basing my coment on the following: *allows me to track exactly what methods were called on this run so that if there is an issue I can see how far it got before breaking making it easy to debug* If there is no issue it doesn't seem to be info he's going to use.

Comment: @InBetween - yes but I dont want to dump the stack - or even care about the stack in some cases - assuming a case like X method was supposed to be called but never did or a number of other scenarios. This way I can chose to update the logging level and change it based on how much I need to print out (Debug, Info, Warrning, Failure). Again, the goal is that info will go on the log when debugging but I dont want to write those lines many many times

Comment: @InBetween I don't read that to mean an Exception was thrown (although that might have been what he meant) - I read that as tracking the functional behaviour of the program to work out how it behaved. It's a fair point though, and you're right to point out that the stack trace will have the information he is looking for if that's how he meant it :) **EDIT** Sam has now clarified that he meant it how I read it - if only English was as unambiguous as C# :)

Comment: Either way, there'll be no exception stack traces with the code as-is: it eats all the exceptions every step of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) Add-ins that will allow you to add this kind of code into your compiled output at compile-time rather than having to write it yourself.

For example, [MethodDecorator](https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator) allows you to define a specific attribute, and any method you decorate with that attribute will call specific methods prior to entering and leaving the method.

I should note that for a project of any reasonable size, logging the entry and exit for every single method is going to produce more log messages than anyone can reasonably expect to read. I'd suggest you be judicious in which methods add log messages, and what information you include in those log messages.

The vast majority of the time a more useful strategy is to use guard statements to test your assumptions along the way, throwing an exception the moment anything is out of place, and then wrapping exceptions with more useful information (via `InnerException`) as they go up the call chain, then finally logging the results of those exceptions at the top level of your application. That way, you only produce log messages when something appears to go in a way you don't expect, and the log message in that case has all the information you're likely to need.

Comment: "allows you to define a specific attribute, and any method you decorate with that attribute will call specific methods prior to entering and leaving the method."

Yup, that sounds like exactly what I am looking for - I will test it out and report back, thank you so much for the info

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work and couldn't. There were no working unit tests with MethodDecorator that I was able to find. I then came across this comment section: https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator/issues/56
In the thread the first reply made me understand why all my attempts were failing: "...I hope someone steps up (sadly I cannot), as Fody has moved forward and no longer supports MethodDecorator in it's current state..."
The concept itself is a great idea and I'll look for others, thank you for exposing me to AOP - (cont. 1/2)

Comment: (2/2) I'll mark this as accepted answer but I hope if someone comes in here they'll read this comment

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, Sam. It's always unfortunate to find that promising projects have fallen by the wayside. You may want to look down the list of Fody add-ins for other libraries that might work. https://github.com/csnemes/tracer seems promising.

Comment: After a few days dealing with this I am finally wrapping my head around the terminology and now I understand it a lot better. That example is perfect, thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but it might point you in the right direction. For demonstration purposes I'm logging to the Console, but you could log to a file instead.

You could create a method that takes in another method to execute, which executes the function and returns the value, and which wraps the beginning and ending of the method call with writes to your log file:

```
// For methods that return a value
private static TResult LogMethod<TResult>(string displayName, Func<TResult> method)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Starting method: {displayName}");
    TResult result = method();
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Completed method: {displayName}");
    return result;
}

// For void methods
private static void LogMethod(string displayName, Action method)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Starting method: {displayName}");
    method();
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Completed method: {displayName}");
}
```

As an example of how to use this, let's say we have the following methods:

```
private static int GetNumberFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int result;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));
    return result;
}

private static int AddNumbers(int first, int second)
{
    return first + second;
}

private static void Tell(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Now, instead of calling these methods directly, we can call them through our `LogMethod` function:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var firstNumber = LogMethod("GetNumber", 
        () => GetNumberFromUser("Enter first number: "));

    var secondNumber = LogMethod("GetNumber", 
        () => GetNumberFromUser("Enter second number: "));

    var result = LogMethod("AddNumber", 
        () => AddNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber));

    LogMethod("Tell", () => Tell($"{firstNumber} + {secondNumber} = {result}"));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone!! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]